# How can I tweak the existing Arabic Keyboard on the iPhone 4, 4.2.1?

Tags: keyboard, arabic, remap

I work in a language which uses an Arabic alphabet, but the existing Arabic keyboard doesn't have at least 5 of the characters I need (the same token it has a whole slew of characters my language doesn't have either).

How can I re-map the Arabic keyboard so that instead of a ة  (U+0629)(on the lower right side of the keyboard) I type my correct ە  (U+06D5)?

I would need to do the same for the other characters I need for my language. I don't need to make a custom keyboard per se, I just need to re-map so I can type my characters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i found this very helpful. http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090725113333249
now i have found the missing arabic letters like ى ء ئ.
hope this method can help you with that problem too

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer and include the essential parts of the solution from that page here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259